# Bytes read / written SNMP value differs from iostat

Tags: linux, snmp, io, iostat

I am trying to monitor my server over SNMP and `UCD-DISKIO-MIB::diskIONRead.1` gives me `1344574464` while `iostat` reports `9701669 kB_read`. Why the discrepancy? I don't have to mention that I am monitoring the correct disk, so that's not the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess at this, but if the logic of this FAQ entry follows,

> ### The system uptime (sysUpTime) returned is wrong!
>
> Oh no it's not.   The defined meaning of 'sysUpTime' is     "the time
>   ... since the *network management*     portion of the system was
>   re-initialized."
>
> In other words, when the snmp agent was started, not when the
>   system itself last booted.

You're probably only getting the amount of bytes written since the monitoring agent started..